# Complex exponentials inequality series proof

Tags: complex-analysis

$(3-e)|z|\leq |e^z-1| \leq (e-1)|z|$ ?

I could attempt: $(3-\sum \frac{1}{n!})|z| \leq  |\sum \frac{z^n}{n!} -1| \leq  (\sum \frac{1}{n!}-1)|z|$, but I'm stuck...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there some condition on the $z$. For arbitrary $z$ the inequality is not going to be true.

If $z$ is a very large real number then $|e^z-1|=e^z-1$ is going to be much larger than $(e-1)|z|=(e-1)z$.

---

If $|z|\leq1$ then $$\left|\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n!}-1\right|=\left|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n!}\right|\leq |z|\cdot\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{|z|^{n-1}}{n!}\leq|z|\cdot\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}=|z|(e-1)$$

For the other inequality we can consider the function $\frac{e^z-1}{z}$. This function is entire after defining it at $z=0$ to be equal to $1$. It also never vanishes. Therefore its reciprocal is entire. By the maximum modulus principle the minimum of $\left|\frac{e^z-1}{z}\right|=|e^z-1|$ on the unit circle should be the minimum of it in the closed unit disc. Therefore it is enough to show that the minimum of this function is not smaller than $3-e$.

For $|z|=1$, $z=x+iy$

$$|e^z-1|^2=e^{2x}-2e^{x}\cos(\sqrt{1-x^2})+1\geq \left(\frac{e-1}{e}\right)^2$$

We can check that $1-\frac{1}{e}>3-e$. In fact, this inequality is equivalent to $e^2-2e-1=(e-1)^2-2>0$, which in turn is equivalent to $e>\sqrt{2}+1$.

Comment: sorry i guess you're right. it's $z$ in a closed disk $\bar{D}(0;1)$